# What does Ctrl+Alt+End is for and how to disable it?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, shortcut-keys, lock-screen

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3 Jammy LTS desktop, and everytime i press Ctrl+Alt+End the screen goes totally black and i can't get back from it.

I know the computer is still responsive because music is still playing, and if i press Ctr+Alt+Supr it restarts gracefully sudenly showing the Ubuntu restart progress.

I found something related to xfce and a mapping of Ctrl+Alt+End but i'm not using xfce, it's not even installed. I'm using Gnome (default setup).

I tried to map that keystroke to a dummy action, like opening calculator but it's still doing the blank screen, so it looks like this goes beyond that.

Any hints?